# Get Image from Canvas Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, google-maps-api-3

I need to get an image from a canvas that is filled with a google map:

```
  ...

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  ...

  var canvas = document.getElementById("map-canvas");
  var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
  var url = canvas.toDataURL();
```

Doesn't work. It's broke up at the second line `"var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");"`. Can anybody help me? Is there a other way to have the same effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this. Your element `map-canvas` isn't a [canvas element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTML/Canvas); it's just an element with an id 'map-canvas'. Canvas methods only work on `<canvas>` elements.